# Java- Reordering the priority of items in the list

Tags: java, reorderlist

I have something like this:

```
    public class TestItem {

        double priority;
        String name;
        String phoneNumber;

        //getter setters
        .
        .
        .

        //action
        public void moveOrder(TestItem before, TestItem after) {

        }
    }
```

I wanted to implement reordering of my list by dragging the list in between the desired items.
Assuming this is my list.

```
    TestItem 1 (priority = 1)
    TestItem 2 (priority = 2)
    TestItem 3 (priority = 3)
    TestItem 4 (priority = 4)
    TestItem 5 (priority = 5)
```

If I want to move TestItem 4 in between 1 and 2, it will become like this:

```
    TestItem 1 (priority = 1)
    TestItem 4 (priority = 1.5)
    TestItem 2 (priority = 2)
    TestItem 3 (priority = 3)

    TestItem 5 (priority = 5)
```

TestItem 4's order is the average of 1 and 2.
My problem is when i keep on reordering, the value of the order becomes smaller.

I dont have any idea yet as to how to correct whenever it reach a something value.
Maybe should I retrieve all the list again? Are there reference as to something implemented like this?

Any suggestion or references is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read about `Collections.sort()` with a `Comparator` ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of the order becomes smaller" and "how to correct whenever it reach a something value"? It is not clear what is "incorrect" about what you describe.

Comment: When Last item will be moved in a loop to position 1 (0-based index), the priorities will be 1.5, 1.25, 1.125, ... and soon it will reach the problem with precision...

Comment: yes, that is what i meant by that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to sort your array selection sort is a simple solution that might work.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

And just make sure you reassign priority, not index

```
public void moveOrder(TestItem before, TestItem after) {
    this.priority = (before.priority + after.priority) / 2.0;
}
```

Hope this helps,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to achieve really.

Division is as bad as multiplying which you will see easier it may overflow...

```
TestItem 1 (priority = 1)
TestItem 2 (priority = 2)
TestItem 3 (priority = 3)
TestItem 4 (priority = 4) // move this between 1 and 2
TestItem 5 (priority = 5)
```

is the sum is odd, multiply all by 2, which will result in

```
   TestItem 1 (priority = 2) // *2
-> TestItem 4 (priority = 3) // (2+4)/2
   TestItem 2 (priority = 4) // *2
   TestItem 3 (priority = 6) // *2
   //TestItem 4 (priority = 4) original position
   TestItem 5 (priority = 10) // *2
```

but you need to access all items in list, if you can do that, simply increment priority for those after new position

```
   TestItem 1 (priority = 1)
-> TestItem 4 (priority = 2) // 1 + 1
   TestItem 2 (priority = 3)
   TestItem 3 (priority = 4)
   //TestItem 4 (priority = 4) original position
   TestItem 5 (priority = 5) // prev. priority + 1
```

Comment: Í'm actually trying to avoid accessing all items of my list as much as possible. and got the kind of implementation from [phabricator's](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/blob/a1ccee8c242e74aa35c245e3d8da206f3c48b16f/src/applications/maniphest/editor/ManiphestTransactionEditor.php) but i got confuse on how he got it corrected.

Comment: do some testing if possible, maybe he didn't ;-) What is expected number of items in your list? If it is 1000s I wouldn't care too much ;-)

Comment: bad because number of moves is limited by power of 2 that fits in the priority type -double so in worst case can support up to 32 moves.

Answer (score -1):

I would use [Priority Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) and its [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#add(E)) and [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#add(E)) methods.

**EDIT**

In case you need to keep a reference to a specific element at any point in time, then having a `Hashmap` with the phone number as a key and the reference to the corresponding priority queue element as a value will do the magic. When you need to reorder, you pick 3 elements from UI (i guess), then you find them in O(1) by `Hashmap` lookup and finally, you have all priorities that you need. You will need to modify the priority of the element you are moving. You do not need to worry about updating the references in the `HashMap` - it will be always updated.

**Example:** List=x,y,z
You need to move x between y and z, so the list looks like y,x,z.
You find x, y and z by doing a Hashmap lookup using their phone numbers. then the new priority of x is:

**p(x)=p(z)-p(y)/2.0**

I assume all the priorities are positive `doubles`. Now your 'list' is reordered.

Good Luck!

Comment: There are no indexes in Priority Queue, there is just min/max element, how you want to move element to 3rd position ?

Comment: by priority. if you want to move x between y and z in the list then p(x)=p(z)-p(y)/2.0

Comment: you do not need to based on the question. you only need to know the priority.

Comment: oh, come on, in question you do not need, because it;s simple in list, but if you are saying "let's use priority queue", you have to solve that too...

Comment: 'come on' what? I do not get what you are saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97384/discussion-between-aviad-and-betlista).